# Visual Studio 2010 and database on server connection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I've spent last 3 hours trying to accomplish something that should be an easy task, and fairly certain I already did it before, but can't seem to make it work again.

I'm running visual studio 2010 and I'm trying to make a new project which would connect to database on my server and can't connect to server.

So, what I did so far?
I have a server and I've made new database (lets call it QARS) using MySql Database Wizzard inside cPanelX
In wizard I've added user (lets say QARSuser) with password (lets say QARSpass).
Lets say I access my server from browser by typing www.QA.com

Now the problem is, how to connect to that database from visual studio.

So far I've tried adding connection, pretty much most permutations I could think of, and still have problem connecting to server.

So how to find out what exactly I have to type in server field?
I assume I use QARSuser and QARSpass as login details?
How to select the database?
I assume connection type is Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)?

Any help appreciated, like I've said, after 3 hours my mind is blank.

PS:
I've did this before in uni, but we got the server address in IP form with login detail which worked right out of the box, so I'm either trying wrong address of server, or I messed up creating the database, or I have no idea :D

Comment: No, you need the [MySql Connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) bits to connect to a MySql Database. You can't use the built-in libraries for Sql Server

Comment: Can you let me know which one I need?
ADO.NET Driver for MySQL (Connector/NET)?

Comment: Yes. ADO.NET is what you want, for connecting .net to MySQL.

Comment: i've run the installer, not sure how to proceed, but still can't connect to my server from visual studio "add connection" window